# fetch() request is send twice with credentials, no preflight

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using `fetch` to get data from my rest server and I'm using this query with Javascript on my client side:

```
            return fetch(
            "http://localhost:443/myressource",  {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            credentials : 'include',
            headers: {
                "Authorization":"Basic " + btoa("test:test"),
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"
            }})
           .then(response => response.text())
           .catch(err => { throw err })
```

Problem with this is that the first request already contains the credentials and usually when you send a request the first request doesn't have credentials and you have to set a realm on server side THEN the browser should send the credentials.

Is there a way to get the fetch work as it should? meaning send the credentials when needed?

Comment: `.catch(err => { throw err })` does nothing.

Comment: Or rather, does something, but it's purely overhead without changing the end result.

Comment: @SLaks i have 
    .catch(err => console.error(err))   in another function.

Comment: @John: That's fine, but there's really no purpose to `.catch(err => { throw err;})` other than to introduce unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% understanding how you determine when they are needed but you could do something like:

```
let config = {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  credentials: 'include',
};

if (neededCondition) {
  config.headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("test:test"),
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"
  };
} 

return fetch( "http://localhost:443/myressource", config)
  .then(response => response.text())
```

Perhaps this could be determined by using sessionStorage and checking if credentials exist there

Comment: Actually i found the correct word it's called "Preflight" meaning that when the browser sends a request, the first request is asking to get the permission to do the action and the second request contains all the information. It's not client side logic it's how normally a request works for cors request.

Comment: Yes...and by setting custom headers browser  will always trigger an OPTIONS (preflight) request when endpoint origin differs from page

Comment: I've added this : 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' in headers and it's still not performing a preflight. And i noticed that if i remove mode: no-cors the fetch sends twice a OPTION request. With mode: no-cors he sends twice a GET request.

Comment: oh yeah... to be honest I haven't used fetch much since it still isn't 100% supported cross browser  and forgot about that `no-cors` mode which I still don't quite understand